# how to do a relative path redirection using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on javascript/jquery in a php based site, and I have to redirect the page upon an event in the page.

lets say, on clicking the button "click me" in `"page1.php"`, the page should be redirected to "`page2.php`". This redirection has to be done using javascript/ jquery. Both pages are in the same folder, and the redirection code should use **'RELATIVE LINKS'**.

Now, I am able to redirect if I give the absolute link to `page2.php`, but could someone let me know how to do the same with a relative link?

something like:

```
window.location.href = 'page2.php';
```

thanks.

Comment: Why don't just use hyperlinks, setting `href` with script, if necessary?

Comment: Your "something like" suggestion should work.

Comment: Oops.. that actually works. The bug due to which redirection was not working in my code was infact due to some other line of code. This line - window.location.href = "whateverpage.php" works, and it is relative path. So I believe redirection is that simple, be it absolute/ relative.
Thanks!

Comment: please flag errostacks or your own answer as correct

Comment: @kritzikratzi - Yes, I tried flagging the appropriate on as the answer, but then StackOverflow requires me to wait for some 2 days before I can do that. Probably something the site should consider reworking, as the author should have the privilege to mark "answered" whenever he wants.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
window.location.href = "page2.php";
```

this worked. Infact, relative and absolute works in the same way:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
// or
window.location.href = "page2.html";
```

Answer (score 13):

You can do a relative redirect:

```
document.location.href = '../'; //one level up
```

or

```
document.location.href = '/path'; //relative to domain
```

or in jquery ...

```
 var url = "http://stackoverflow.com";    
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

Answer (score 6):

To set a relative path use `window.location.pathname`.

Take a look at the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) on [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location):

Comment: If you are on, say, http://example.com/index.html, then `window.location.pathname` will be `/index.html`

Comment: @unclenorton, I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: I mean that, if there is filename in path, like index.html, or index.php, or whatever else, it will get into `window.location.pathname`. For example, go to http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/documentation.html and type check `window.location.pathname` in javascript console.

Comment: Yes, because that's the path that you're currently located to.  For it to contain the filename is valid.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand, if you are on http://example.com/path/to/page1.php, and you click on "page2.php", you would like to be redirected to http://example.com/path/to/page2.php ?

Perhaps there is a smarter solution, but does it solve your problem ?

```
function relativeRedir(redir){
  location.pathname = location.pathname.replace(/(.*)\/[^/]*/, "$1/"+redir);
}
```

Example of use : relativeRedir("page1.php");

Comment: I think this is the only multi-browser solution. `document.location.href` does work in IE and Chrome but it does not work in FF.

Comment: If anyone is still reading this, that's because it should be `window.location.href`.