# Page.ResolveUrl is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In jQuery code I'm using `ResolveUrl("~/DynamicMenu.ashx")`.

But it just returns the exact string:

> `"ResolveUrl("~/DynamicMenu.ashx")"`

Here is a bit of code:

```
pageIndex = pageIndex + 1;
var CountryCode = getCookie("SetCountry");
var urlToHandler = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/DynamicMenu.ashx") %>'; 
urlToHandler = urlToHandler + CountryCode + "&PageIndex=" + pageIndex;
alert(urlToHandler);
```

What is wrong in my code for **ResolveUrl()**?

Comment: i don't see a **javascript** call to `ResolveUrl`. From javascript perspective `'<%= ResolveUrl("~/DynamicMenu.ashx") %>'` is a *string*, it is your ASP application that is supposed to run that code

Comment: yeah this has nothing to do with javascript. it's asp.net, and i know i've had problems with server tags in javascript code

Comment: <% var siteroot = Url.Content("~/") %>

Answer (score 2):

The problem, as *poncha* pointed out, is that as far as ASP.NET is concerned, the content delivered in your .js file is a string.  It does not apply any sort of rendering before IIS delivers it.  It gets the same treatment any other *content* file would, like a `.jpg` or `.png`.

In order to call server side methods (like `ResolveUrl`), you need to use the `<% ... %>` syntax within any page that is *parsed* by ASP.NET (like an `.aspx` or `.master` file).

---

By the way, these little code blocks go by a lot of different names:

> - [Inline Expressions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112)
> - [Embedded Code Blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135(v=vs.100).ASPX)
> - [Code Nuggets](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/16/asp-net-mvc-3-implicit-and-explicit-code-nuggets-with-razor.aspx)
> - [Server Side Script Delimiters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa239615(v=vs.60).aspx)
> - [Code Render Blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z(v=vs.100).aspx)
> - [ASP Directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524741(v=vs.90).aspx#aspdirectives)

---

In particular, we want a [*Displaying Expression*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5.aspx) with the syntax `<%= ... %>`, where:

> the value that is entered after the equals sign is written into the current page

Knowing that, we can build our own own URL by using [`ResolveClientUrl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx) which:

> returns a URL string suitable for use by the client to access resources on the Web server

To this, we'll pass in the [**Web Application Root Operator**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx) or `~` character, where ASP.NET:

> resolves the ~ operator to the root of the current application:

By combining these, we can save the result of the displaying expression into a JavaScript variable by placing the following code on your Master Page (adapted from [Joel Varty's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2009/07/17/resolveurl-in-javascript.aspx)):

```asp
<script type="text/javascript">
    var baseUrl = '<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/") %>';
</script>
```

Since JavaScript variables are inherently global, any other script can now access the `baseUrl` variable, so we can utilize it from the .js file with the following script:

```
function ResolveUrl(url) {
    return url.replace("~/", baseUrl);
}
```

Now you can call `ResolveUrl("~/DynamicMenu.ashx")` directly from your javascript file and it will create the appropriate URL by stripping out "~/" and replacing it with the baseUrl created earlier by the server side script.

---

Further Reading:

- [What is the difference between ResolveUrl and ResolveClientUrl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1874636/1366033)
- [Relative Urls](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution - [ResolveUrl in Javascript](http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2009/07/17/resolveurl-in-javascript.aspx)

Comment: can i try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547709/working-with-uri-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028737/how-to-do-a-relative-path-redirection-using-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310620/how-to-get-relative-path-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188218/relative-paths-in-javascript-in-an-external-file

Comment: @user384080 -- care to elaborate? I actually think it's a perfect solution.